# Does google cloud havea storage gateway concept like AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

Does google cloud have a storage gateway concept like AWS? 
AWS has the following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html
Does google cloud have a similar solution? I didnt get anything in the documentation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the scenario that you're trying to support?  There are other options for data movement that might not require a gateway.

Comment: I have a 1 TB hard disk attached to a Linux and/or AIX system which has LVM. I want to copy that data to google cloud/aws/ibm cloud. It may be disk cloned to a image file or copy the volume group or some other way?Whats the best way?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - for 1 TB you can probably just use gsutil (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to copy the image/files to your Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud does not currently support a storage gateway.